# No rule to make target for googletest

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

Scraping the rust off my C++ after many, many years. Lots of new things including CmakeLists.txt. I'm using CLION and googletest, both of which I'm also new to.

I followed the tutorial https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Cpp_project_setup_with_cmake_and_unit_tests.html to set up unit testing for a basic project. Now I'm trying to adapt that project to my test project.

I have changed the library structure. The src directory still contains my source and tst my test, but I have created a lib directory and a git submodule for googletest there.

Here is my root CmakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(processcontroller_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include_directories(src)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(tst)
add_subdirectory(lib/googletest)
```

and here is the one for src

```
set(BINARY ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES LIST_DIRECTORIES true *.h *.cpp)

set(SOURCES ${SOURCES})

add_executable(${BINARY}_run ${SOURCES})

add_library(${BINARY}_lib STATIC ${SOURCES})
```

and the one for tst

```
set(BINARY ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_tst)

file(GLOB_RECURSE TEST_SOURCES LIST_DIRECTORIES false *.h *.cpp)

set(SOURCES ${TEST_SOURCES})

add_executable(${BINARY} ${TEST_SOURCES})

add_test(NAME ${BINARY} COMMAND ${BINARY})

target_link_libraries(${BINARY} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_lib gtest)
```

Now when I run the tests using tst/main.cpp I get:

```
====================[ Build | processcontroller_test_tst | Debug ]==============
/opt/clion/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/thomas/CLionProjects/processcontroller-test/cmake-build-debug --target processcontroller_test_tst -- -j 12
gmake[3]: *** No rule to make target 'src/CMakeFiles/processcontroller_test_lib.dir/build'.  Stop.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:227: src/CMakeFiles/processcontroller_test_lib.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 40%] Built target gtest
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:262: tst/CMakeFiles/processcontroller_test_tst.dir/rule] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:210: processcontroller_test_tst] Error 2
```

I think the problem is in the last line of my tst/CMakeLists.txt file

```
target_link_libraries(${BINARY} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_lib gtest)
```

But I can't see how. Tried reading from the docs about this but can't seem to make heads or tails of it.

I added `message(STATUS "Source list:" ${SOURCES})` to the src make file and `message(STATUS "Test source list:" ${SOURCES})` to the tst make and got these results.

```
-- Source list:/home/thomas/CLionProjects/processcontroller-test/src/water-dispenser.h
-- Test source list:/home/thomas/CLionProjects/processcontroller-test/tst/Arduino-mock.h/home/thomas/CLionProjects/processcontroller-test/tst/main.cpp/home/thomas/CLionProjects/processcontroller-test/tst/water-dispenser-test.cpp
```

Comment: The path to the absent target (`src/CMakeFiles/processcontroller_test_lib.dir/build`) is weird. It seems that this path (or its relative variant) is used in your `CMakeLists.txt`. I would suspect that `LIST_DIRECTORIES true` is responsible for it. Try to print (via `message()` command) `SOURCES` variable in your sub-`CMakeLists.txt` and check that it contains only expected files.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Updated the question with the results. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand these things, but everything I tried failed. Finally I just dumped the project started a new one, recreated everything step by step with the same make files and everything's now working. Something jammed up in CLion.

You can tell that Clion is not JetBrains's flagship product. They need to focus on it a bit more.